# I want to write terminal errors to a log file - LUMEN

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel, lumen

I am using [LUMEN](http://lumen.laravel.com/) framework.

I want to log or write all those errors which appears in console or terminal to a log file. So that I can see what errors are appearing in the process.

Currently I am running my LUMEN server using this command:

```
nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon & ?
```

So how can I get all those error in a log file?

Example errors I want to log:

```
    [Mon Jul  6 13:39:12 2015] 127.0.0.1:36615 [500]: /v1/user/fetchUser/ -
 Class 'App\Http\Controllers\V1\UserController' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/api/app/Http/Controllers/V1/ArticleController.php on line 504

[Tue Jul  7 11:11:59 2015] 127.0.0.1:37774 [500]: /v1/user/fetchUsers/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect the output to a file like this:

`nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon > ./queue_worker.log &`

To save the terminal output to one file and errors to another:

`nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon > output.log 2> errors.log &`

Comment: I am getting this error: nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout

Comment: It is just letting you know that the standard output as well as any errors are redirected to file instead of the terminal.

Comment: I am getting this error on my log file only:

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Memcached' not found in /var/www/mysite.com/v1/vendor/illuminate/cache/MemcachedConnector.php on line 51

Comment: I have generated too many errors but it only log this specific error. No other errors are written. Only this single line

Comment: Use `>>` instead of `>` to append to the file, rather than overwriting it each time. And I forgot to add the `&` so it continues to run in the background.

Comment: I tried the updated command you provided. Now its appending the same error again and again. 
i.e
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Memcached' not found in /var/www/mysite.com/v1/vendor/illuminate/cache/MemcachedConnector.php on line 51
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Memcached' not found in /var/www/mysite.com/v1/vendor/illuminate/cache/MemcachedConnector.php on line 51

It is not appending those errors which are appearing on terminal/console. I need to append those errors which are appearing in console

Comment: I've updated my answer with a command to seperate the output from errors.

Comment: The errors.log is the same as it was, it contains the same error as before. And the output.log is empty. I want my errors in output.log file

Comment: you are using "stderr" add & before  >   for more details visit http://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file

Answer (score 0):

Example: `nohup ruby post_receive.rb >> /root/logPostReceive.log 2>&1 &` 
**2>&1** redirect stderr to stdout